# Solutions of coursera ruby on rails assignment

Tags: ruby, rspec, coursera-api

I am doing a specialization in rails .Its assignment is related to find maximum frequency words.I solve it all but it cant pass one test out of 19.Anybody doing that?

Comment: Include your code to check the problem. Please look at [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Flagged: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finished the assignment with no errors, you may just have a typo in your answer. If you post your code it would be easier to help you. A sample solution has been posted on GitHub [Max-word-frequency](https://github.com/whoismikechan/Coursera-Ruby-On-Rails/blob/master/module02/assignment-Calc-Max-Word-Freq/module2_assignment.rb).

Comment: Thankuuuuuuuuuuuu , thankuuuuuuuuuu soooooo muchhhh :). A lot of prayers for you :)